# HTTP request header is removed in Google cloud run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-run

When I try to send a HTTP post request from my UI to the Google cloud run hosted backend, the header named `x-google-token` is automatically removed. Tried with CURL as well. Another header named `x-fb-token` is working fine though. Could someone please explain what's happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this article which explains the problem. As it turns out, Google cloud run removes headers with  names that match the X-Google-* pattern from incoming requests because those patterns are reserved for Google.

> The following headers are removed from incoming requests if a client
> sends them:
>
> Headers with names that match the X-Google-* pattern. This name
> pattern is reserved for Google.

Here is the full article:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/reference/request-response-headers